# IdentityServer4 External Authentication (Azure Active Directory) fails

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1

I created project from template: "**is4aspid**" and added Azure Active Directory authentication.
In Startup.cs added this code:

```cs
  // preserve OIDC state in cache (solves problems with AAD and URL lenghts)
  services.AddOidcStateDataFormatterCache();
  // cookie policy to deal with temporary browser incompatibilities
  services.AddSameSiteCookiePolicy();

  services.AddAuthentication()
          .AddOpenIdConnect("aad", "Sign-in with Azure AD", options =>
          {
                    options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
                    options.ClientId = "myClientId";
                    options.ClientSecret = "myClientSecret";

                    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                    options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;

                    options.ResponseType = "id_token";
                    options.CallbackPath = "/signin-aad";
                    options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/signout-callback-aad";
                    options.RemoteSignOutPath = "/signout-aad";

                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidateAudience = false,
                        NameClaimType = "name",
                        RoleClaimType = "role"
                    };
          });
```

I added redirect uri on Azure: http://localhost:5000/signin-aad

Error occure where Callback method is called.
HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme) *Success* is always **false**

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Callback()
{
    var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);
    if (result?.Succeeded != true)
    {
       throw new Exception("External authentication error");
    }
    // some code
}
```

Where is my error?

Answer (score 0):

[Solution](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/4231)

Must define IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme in startup and callback